# Expected Value of 4th Order Statistic

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expectation, order-statistics, exponential-distribution

I am trying to solve for the expected value of fourth order statistic, $$E[X_{(4)}].  $$

Suppose I have the following random variables:

$$ X_1, X_2, ... X_5 $$

With pdf: 
$$ f(x) = e^{-x}  $$ $$ x>0 $$

And their corresponding order statistics:

$$ X_{(1)} < X_{(2)} ... <X_{(5)}$$

First, I have solved for the CDF: 
$$ F(x) = \int_0^x{f(t)}dt = (1-e^{-x})$$

Using the following equation for the PDF of the kth order statistic, I have found the PDF of the 4th order statistic.

$$f_{x_{(k)}} =  n f(x)*\begin{pmatrix} n-1\\k-1\end{pmatrix} *F(x)^{k-1}*(1-F(x))^{n-k}$$

$$f_{x_{(4)}} =  5*e^{-x}*\begin{pmatrix} 5-1\\4-1\end{pmatrix} *(1-e^{-x})^{4-1}*(1-F(x))^{5-4}$$

$$f_{x_{(4)}} =  20e^{-2x}(1-e^{-x})^3  $$

Now to solve for the expected value, $E[X_{(4)}].  $

$$ E[X_{(4)}] = \int_0^{\infty}x*f_{x_{(4)}}dx$$

$$ E[X_{(4)}] = \int_0^{\infty}x*20e^{-2x}(1-e^{-x})^3 dx$$

$$ E[X_{(4)}] = ? $$

First, I am not sure that I can possibly evaluate this integral analytically, and I would be fine to evaluate numerically.  However, when I try to evaluate numerically using a tool like Wolfram, it says that the integral does not converge, and it will not solve.

Can somebody please verify that I have taken the correct approach and applied all formulas correctly.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Expand $(1-e^{-x})^3$ and use the fact that, for every positive $a$, $$\int_0^\infty xe^{-ax}dx=\frac1{a^2}$$

Comment: If you want a neat trick, you should consider the exponential spacings: http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/Devroye_files/chapter_five.pdf P.6 (P. 211)
Otherwise your approach should be fine. I have not check your formula, but you can always expand the bracket inside and you should have easy gamma integral afterward. You may also consider integrate $1 - F(x)$ in which may involve similar expansion

Comment: With $n$ independent exponential random variables with individual rate $\lambda$ (i.e. mean $\frac1\lambda$), the combined rate until the first event is $n\lambda$.  Memorylessness lets you apply this four times here and add up the expectations